# i m using calling function from a class and using it from another class

Tags: java, android

i want to make a phone call from my application but while calling i m getting an error, so basically i make a class in which i write a function for calling and when i call it from another activity it doesnt get connected,pls help me in this to solve this problem

here is my code

```
ListWarrenty.java
public class ListWarrenty extends Fragment {
    private ListView lv1;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_warrenty, container, false);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Ace Brain Systems & Software Pvt Ltd - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "1559, SADASHIV PETH,\n" +
                "Phone: 20 - 4335871 /72, 4329730 /31 /32\n" +
                "yogesh@acebrain.com, service@acebrain.com");
        list.add( "Cms Computers Ltd - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "Bhosari Complex,Unit No. 24,\n" +
                "stores.pune@cms.com");
        list.add("Computer Home - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "Plot No-562,,Africana, Shyamsundar Society Lane,\n" +
                "Phone:  20 - 24327327, 32544448\n" +
                "jsushil@computer-home.com");
        list.add("Glodyne Technoserve Ltd - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "Office No.103 &104, Monoplex Plaza,\n" +
                "Mobile:  9520202519");


        list.add("Network Integrators ( India ) Pvt Ltd - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "A-15, Ground Floor,Pavan Industrial Estate,\n" +
                "info@niplindia.com");

        list.add("Real Time Services - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "Plot No-562,,Africana,\n" +
                "Phone:  20 - 24327327, 32544448\n" +
                "jsushil@computer-home.com");

        list.add("Spicenet India Ltd - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "Flat no.5, Bldg no.1, Plot no.285,,New Lakshminarayan\n" +
                "kishore.b@spicelimited.com");

        list.add("Support Technologies - Acer Laptop Service Center in Pune\n" +
                "Purva Plaza, Flat# 3,515,\n" +
                "Phone:  20 - 24431608, 56012893\n" +
                "supporttech@iqara.net");


        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(list, getActivity());

        //handle listview and assign adapter

        lv1= (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);

       // ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
  return rootview;
    }

}
```

and here is my adapter class

MyCustomAdapter.java

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;
    TextView listItemText1;
    TextView listItemText;
    Button emailBtn,callButton;

    public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
     //   return list.get(pos).getId();
        return 0;
        //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        }
        //Handle TextView and display string from your list

        listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

//         listItemText1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
//        listItemText1.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        emailBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

        callButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

        emailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Email();
//                //do something
//                list.remove(position); //or some other task
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                call();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void call() {

        try{
            String url2 = "0000000000";
            Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(url2));
            context.startActivity(in);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Your call is not get connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private void Email() {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Your Mail has been sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        //Toast.makeText("Your Activity is not founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `i m getting an error` Surely details of the error are a vital part of the question... lets start with compile time or runtime?

Comment: WHat type of error are you getting?  A crash?  Post the stack trace.  It isn't working?  Step through in a debugger and figure out where things go sideways.  Don't just say "this doesn't work" and expect us to put in the work to guess the answer.

Comment: actually it executes the catch part directly from call() Function

Comment: the URI is wrong, it has to be of the form tel:xxxxx -> check my answer for details...

Answer (score 0):

Well the URI you are passing is wrong which is why it can't place any calls.Do something like this:

```
 String uri = "tel:00000000" ;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

This will open the dialer for you and you can press call...... This does not require any permissions....

If you want to directly try to call, you will need CALL permission in manifest and if the device is above 6.0 android, you will also have to probably ask for permission at runtime -> android.permission.CALL_PHONE

After getting the permissions do the following:

```
 String uri = "tel:00000000" ;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure to call this in a try block as well, as anybody can potentially reject the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And add this code in your activity

```
String uri = "tel:"+number      //in your case number = "0000000000";
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Or You can Use like this. Both the ways are correct to call a number.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+8802177690));   //change the number  
startActivity(callIntent);
```